# can't get discord to recognize my role id?

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

```
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import random
import glob
import os.path
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.content.startswith(
            "/roles") and ctx.author.id == 251419567954460673:
        await roles(ctx)


async def roles(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(1047136010456285214)
    await channel.purge()
    text = "everyone choose a role\nKomt = ☑️\nSlapen = ️"
    message = await channel.send(text)
    await message.add_reaction("☑️")
    await message.add_reaction("️")

    def check(r: discord.Reaction, u: discord.User):
        return u.id == ctx.author.id and r.message.channel.id == ctx.channel.id and str(
            r.emoji) in ["☑️", "️"]

    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add',
                                               check=check,
                                               timeout=None)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(
            f"**{ctx.author}**, you didnt react with a ☑️ or ️ in time.")
        return
    else:
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "☑️":
            print("komt role selected")
            role_id = 1047136385036980224
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)
            await user.add_roles(role)

        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "️":
            print("slapen role selected")
            role_id = 1047136293173342258
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)
            await user.add_roles(role)


my_secret = os.environ['DISCORDKEY']
client.run(my_secret)
keep_alive()
```

So I created this code (mostly of the help of looking up and such) and I am trying to create a bot that adds roles to a user that chooses on of the reaction I got almost everything working fine.

The only problem that still remains is that discord doesn't recognize these roles as actual role id's which they are since I copied them from my server

above is all the code I have.

Answer (score 0):

For other people: The problem might be your role id. Try grabbing the role id from the roles page in server settings instead of from a message. [What the page looks like in the unlikely case you don't know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHUn5.png)
Role ids are usually 18 digits long but newly created roles may be 19.

The error in this case was that he lacked intents in `client = discord.Client()`

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```

Intents must both be enabled in your code and in the developer portal.

Comment: I just checked again it gives me the same number for both the roles so i am pretty sure it is correct

i got these id's by going to roles in server settings right clicking and copy id on the bottom

Comment: I tested your exact code with my ids, it works. Check your ids again, your channel id also seems to be wrong (19 digits)

Comment: Found the mistake on my part: your roles are just very new so your role ids are 19 digits long. I based by original answer on what you said the error output was "discord doesn't recognize these roles as actual role id's" when since the error was in "client = discord.Client()", the error output would be completely different. For other questions do include the error output, not just what you think it is.

Comment: That is really weird but i just made another comment that i fixed the problem it was something i had to enable on the discord developer portal now everything works fine